# How to convert an MP4 to a text file and back

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-3.x, mp4

I need to be able to convert a .mp4 to a plaintext. I dont mean the speech, i mean convert it to characters and convert it back. Ive looked at a couple programs but they only convert the speech, i need the whole thing to be turned into a text file or have the charaters be copyable to a text file, and put back into the program to make it a video. I did look at other discussions and they didnt seem to fit. Thanks!

Comment: You can use base64encode and base64decode for that

Comment: why do you need it to be a text file?

Comment: Depending on what you consider "text"... https://ayende.com/blog/177729/emoji-encoding-a-new-style-for-binary-encoding-for-the-web

Comment: "thing to be turned into a text file": see above about the base64encode/decode.  "or have the charaters be copyable to a text file": so you mean if this is a video with text take that text and convert them to txt? something like OCR(Optical character recognition)?

Comment: Have a look at [uuencode](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uuencode) before you reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [uu](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uu.html) library:

```
import uu

uu.encode('video.mp4', 'video.txt')
uu.decode('video.txt', 'video-copy.mp4')
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the file into plaintext

```
import base64

# Load this source file and strip the header. You can try removing .split('#end_pymotw_header')[1] from end.
initial_data = open("video.mp4", 'rt').read().split('#end_pymotw_header')[1]

encoded_data = base64.b64encode(initial_data)

num_initial = len(initial_data)
padding = { 0:0, 1:2, 2:1 }[num_initial % 3]

print '%d bytes before encoding' % num_initial
print 'Expect %d padding bytes' % padding
print '%d bytes after encoding' % len(encoded_data)
print
#print encoded_data
for i in xrange((len(encoded_data)/40)+1):
    print encoded_data[i*40:(i+1)*40]
```

Writing back to mp4 file.

```
temp_path = tempfile.gettempdir()
video_binary_string = 'AAAAIGZ0eXBpc29tAAACAGlzb21p...' #it's base64.b64encode text
decoded_string = base64.b64decode(video_binary_string) 

with open(temp_path+'/video.mp4', 'wb') as wfile:
   wfile.write(decoded_string)
```

Click [here](https://pymotw.com/2/base64/) for more details.